# Determining all $f : \Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ satisfying $f\bigl(f(x)f(y)\bigr)+f(x+y)=f(xy)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> Let $\Bbb R$ be the set of real numbers. Determine all functions $f : \Bbb R \to\Bbb R$ such that, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$,
> $$f\bigl(f(x)f(y)\bigr)+f(x+y)=f(xy)\text.$$

**My attempt:** Let's first find some partial answers. If this equation has some polynomial answers of degree $d$ then the coefficient of $x^d$ must be equal at both sides i.e. we must have
$$\max\left\{d^2,d\right\}=d$$
which leads to
$$d=0,1$$
now let's take the general answer of polynomial kind as
$$f(x)=ax+b$$
for some $a$ and $b$. Substituting this in the equation leads to
$$f\left(a^2xy+b^2+abx+aby\right)+ax+ay+b=axy+b$$
which leads to
$$a^3xy+ab^2+a^2bx+a^2by+b+ax+ay=axy$$
finally we obtain one trivial answer $a=b=0$ and two non-trivial answers
$$a=-b=1\\a=-b=-1$$
therefore the only non-trivial polynomials satisfying the equation above are
$$f(x)=x-1\\f(x)=-x+1$$
I believe these are the only answers of the question. Here turns out two questions:

> 1. Are there any other answers except those I found?
> 2. If so, what are they?

Comment: Can we manipulate this to say that $f(0)\in \{ 0,\pm 1\}$?

Comment: I don't think so, or if is it this is not a strong background implication. How can you prove that for example $f(0)\ne 2$?

Comment: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2017SL.pdf

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is continuous, then $0,-x+1$, and $x-1$ are the only possible functions.

Assume $b \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(b) = 0$. Then $y=b \implies f(0)+f(x+b) = f(xb)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Now unless $b=1$, we can let $x = \frac{b}{b-1}$ so that $x+b = xb$ and thus $f(0)=0$. But then $y=0 \implies f(0)+f(x) = f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $f \equiv 0$. Hence, we may assume $f(b) = 0 \implies b=1$.

Now $x=y=0$ implies $f(0)^2 = 1$. Assume $f(0) = 1$. [The case $f(0) = -1$ follows from replacing $f$ by $-f$, which is a symmetry the main functional equation respects]. Then, $y=1 \implies f(x+1) = f(x)-1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(0) = 1 \implies f(x) = -x+1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Also, for each $x \not = 1$, letting $y = \frac{x}{x-1}$ gives that $f(f(x)f(\frac{x}{x-1})) = 0 \implies f(x)f(\frac{x}{x-1}) = 1$. Letting $x = \frac{1}{2}$ shows $f(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x+1) = f(x)-1$ gives that $f(\frac{k}{2}) = -\frac{k}{2}+1$ for each $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. It's then an easy induction (on the size of denominator), using $f(x)f(\frac{x}{x-1}) = 1$, to conclude that $f(\frac{p}{q}) = -\frac{p}{q}+1$ for each $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, q \not = 0$. [The point is that $\frac{x}{x-1}$ at $x = \frac{p}{q}$ is $\frac{p}{p-q}$ which has denominator smaller than $q$ in absolute value.]

Hence, $f(x) = -x+1$ for each $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and if $f$ is continuous, this extends to all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You haven't prove the existence of $b$.

Comment: Yes I have. $x=y=0$ implies $f(f(0)^2) = 0$. This is how I got $f(0)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Also, I note that for each $x \not = 1$, $f(f(x)f(\frac{x}{x-1})) = 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Seems that you mixed what is cause and what is consequence.

Comment: @greedoid I don't see an issue. Right away you can take $x=y=0$ to see that $f(f(0)^2) = 0$. So that gives you the existence of some $b$ for which $f(b) = 0$. But anyways the paragraph starting with "Assume" is just the implication $f(b) = 0 \implies b=1$.

Comment: @mathworker21: Nice proof!